# Is it possible to set the target audience (kids or no kids) with the youtube data api when I upload a video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

here is an example from the yt-data.api docs

```
python upload_video.py --file="/tmp/test_video_file.flv"
                       --title="Summer vacation in California"
                       --description="Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz"
                       --keywords="surfing,Santa Cruz"
                       --category="22"
                       --privacyStatus="private"
```

Is there a way to set it for kids or not for kids?

[Img of youtube upload settings where you can set the audience (kids or no kids)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZQO7.png)

I read the docs and searched the internet but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user Gaurav Joshi mentioned that:

“…in the status field you can add a property called "selfDeclaredMadeForKids". You can set its value as True or False.”

```
status=dict(
        privacyStatus='public',
        selfDeclaredMadeForKids=False 
    )
```

Maybe try adding something like this?

```
python upload_video.py --file="/tmp/test_video_file.flv"
                       --title="Summer vacation in California"
                       --description="Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz"
                       --keywords="surfing,Santa Cruz"
                       --category="22"
                       —-privacyStatus="private”
                       —-selfDeclaredMadeForKids=“True/False”
```